# Breakpoints Very Wide Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Anyone know how I will be able to fix the problem of the very wide breakpoint annotations interface?. See the right side of my picture. I'm using eclipse luna ubuntu 14.04 and JRE 1.8 [image].

Comment: It's a little hard to tell *exactly* what to look at. Maybe you should draw a circle or rectangle around it.

Comment: That is the PyDev Overview Ruler Minimap, see the duplicate for details